# How to save a file within a hidden input in a POST form?

Tags: laravel, file, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.8

I'm currently on a `laravel 5.8` + `vue.js 2` project and I want to be able to upload an array of files in a form so it can appear inside the form data and saved.

Inside my form there is a Vue component, made to display the intended files to upload:

```
<input
        name="documents[0][files]"
        accept="image/*,application/pdf"
        type="hidden"
        v-model="files"
    >
```

It has `file` as its model:

```
data(){
    return{
        files: null,
        types: {},
        label: 'Seleccionar Archivo',
        selected_file: null,
        file_type_id: '',
        file_types: null
    }
},
```

Within methods, `onSelectFile` assigns the file to a data variable, then it's sent to `addNewFile`, so said value may come to `file`, the model:

```
onSelectFile(e){
        if(!e.target.files.length) return;
        this.selected_file = e.target.files[0];
        this.addNewFile(this.selected_file);
        e.target.value = null;
    },

    addNewFile(file){
        this.files = file;       
    },
```

However, when it's time to save and store. The `formData` on File looks like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s96U9.png)

Action sends you to the store method in the controller, which sends you to the `addPolicy` function:

```
public function store(StorePolicy $request)
{        
    Policy::addPolicy($request->validated());
```

`addPolicy` does a DB transaction for all data (in this case I'll only show what it does to save the file):

```
public static function addPolicy(array $data)
    {      
        DB::transaction(function () use($data) {
            if ( isset($data['documents']) ) {
                foreach($data['documents'] as $files){
                    $policy->documents()->create([
                        'file' => $files['files']->file('file')->store($policy->employee->urlFolderEmployee(), 'public'),
                        'file_name' => $files['files']->file('file')->getClientOriginalName()
                    ]);
                }
            }

            return $policy;
        });
    }
```

However, the lines of code above never save said file, because it's recognized as a String instead of `(binary)`.

Whenever I want to `getClientOriginalName()` for example it displays the error:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on string
```

I've also set the form to accept files:

```
{!! Form::open(
                [
                    'route'=>['policy.store'] ,
                    'method'=>'POST', 
                    'id' => 'form_register_new_policy_modal', 
                    'data-prefix' => "{$register}",
                    'data-modal' => "register_policy_modal",
                    'files' => true
                ])     
            !!}
```

Is there any way to get the file inside of the input data as a file instead of a string?

Comment: Please post the **rendered HTML** of your `<form>`. Are you using the correct `enctype`?